# Annoying strcat() output

Tags: c, text, strcmp

I'm having some unknown problem with using strings. It only happens at the instance of this kind of algorithm:

Source.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    int cur, max;
    char ast[32];
    printf("Enter the triangle's size: ");
    scanf("%d", &max);
    for(cur = 1; cur <= max; cur++)
    {
        strcat(ast, "*");
        if(cur == 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%s\n", ast);
    }
    getch();
}
```

This happens:

---

Overview: A program that creates a triangle out of asterisks (*) of
an inputted size.

---

Enter the triangle's size: 5

■   Z☼]vYⁿbv░↓@*

■   Z☼]vYⁿbv░↓@**

■   Z☼]vYⁿbv░↓@***

■   Z☼]vYⁿbv░↓@****

■   Z☼]vYⁿbv░↓@*****

---

It's supposed to look like this:

Enter triangle size: 5

```
*

**

***

****

*****
```

I don't know why. Can someone please help? :)

Comment: Its supposed to look like this:

*
**
***
****
*****

Comment: Use an initialiser like this: `char ast[32] = "";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string `ast` is not initialized, so it will contain *garbage*, to which you append stuff.

Init it first - you need a zero terminated string, set the first character to `'\0'`.

Comment: It still gives garbage. How should I initialize the line. I tried 

ast[0] = '\0';

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to be some problem with the compiler during runtime. I retried this one, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ast[0]=0;
```

will fix it - aka initialize it

Comment: It goes "invalid initializer".

Answer (score 0):

alternative using snprintf:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define MAX 32
 int main(void)
 {
     unsigned int cur, max;
     char ast[32];
     printf("Enter the triangle's size: ");
     scanf("%d", &max);
     if (max > MAX)
    return -1;
     for(cur = 1; cur <= max; cur++)
     {
     if(cur == 1)
         {
          snprintf(ast,2,"*");
              printf("\n");
         }
     else 
          strlcat(ast, "*",cur + 1);
     printf("%s\n", ast);
    }
    return 0;
}
```